# How to resolve "_vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888", referenced from: ERROR?

Tags: ios, avcapture

When I am converting RGBA to ARGB, I used this code:

```
vImage_Buffer src;
src.height = height;
src.width = width;
src.rowBytes = srcBytesPerRow;
src.data = srcRows;

vImage_Buffer dest;
dest.height = height;
dest.width = width;
dest.rowBytes = destBytesPerRow;
dest.data = destRows;

// Swap pixel channels from BGRA to RGBA.
const uint8_t map[4] = { 2, 1, 0, 3 };
vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888(&src, &dest, map, kvImageNoFlags);
```

I am getting the error below: For that I added `Convertion.h` and `Accelerate.framework`.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
>   "_vImagePermuteChannels_ARGB8888", referenced from:
>         -[CCOverlayView processImage] in CCOverlayView.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be seeing one of two problems:

1) This routine is located in the `Accelerate.framework`. You need to add this to your project.

2) This routine is only available in iOS 5.0 and later; you probably should not be including armv6 in these builds. (The devices that require armv6 cannot run iOS 5.0).

Comment: Hi idz,Apple doc mention this is available from mac 10.4.1. It means below iOS5.0 also. i added Accelerate.Framework also but no use.

Comment: Eh, not it doesn't Mac OS X is a different OS and it's version numbers have no relation to iOS'. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_conversion/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005488-CH210-DontLinkElementID_4 Follow this link and scroll down to the availability section: "Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later."

Comment: can i re-size AVCamra capture size Actually AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium is 480X360  AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium is 192x162 but i want 320X192; i am using iOS 4.2.1

Comment: Best to ask that a separate question!